# Unlocked boot loader ADB issue

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, boot, rom

So I’m trying to downgrade my nexus 6P from Oreo 8.1 to 7.xx. I’ve unlocked the boot loader and can communicate with the device through Google’s adb fast boot command line which works fine (up to a point) I get this far and it fails every time. Here’s the files I’m trying to flash. Is there something I’m missing? I’ve installed google usb drivers too as I thought that was the issue

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHqmk.jpg

I’d like to pay whoever can resolves the issue, can send crypto

Comment: You should open the `flash-all.bat` file in an editor and check which fastboot command it tries to execute after displaying `checking version baseband`.